# vega: when are transforms the right choice?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm going to be using vega and vega-lite to produce many different interactive visualizations for a website that will showcase the data collected by a large, multi-year survey project.

I'm new to using vega/vega-lite on a project of this scale and am trying to work out which things I should do with vega/vega-lite and which things are better done with other tools.

More specifically, I'm wondering when (if ever) I ought to filter or reshape data using vega's data transformation tools.  If I understand vega correctly, it seems like transformations will occur at runtime in a user's browser when they visit the url where I post a visualization.  Given this, it seems to me that if I want things to run quickly for my users, I ought to keep use of vega's transformations to an absolute minimum (at least for visualizations backed by large datasets).  Instead, my guess is that I ought to do as much re-shaping as possible at build time (say, by running R scripts).  And when a visualization needs to allow a user to explore different views of the data, that ought to be done by switching at runtime between pre-shaped, pre-loaded datasets rather than running transformation code on demand.

But in googling, I haven't been able to find much written about suggested architectures for large vega/vega-lite projects, so I'm just guessing here.

So...

1. Can anyone suggest general guidelines for when to use vega's transformations at runtime and instead when to switch at runtime between pre-shaped datasets?
2. Can anyone point me to more general suggestions about the architecture of relatively large projects based on vega/vega-lite visualizations?

Thanks!

To be clear, I haven't tested specific alternatives at this point.  Just trying to get a sense of what others with experience with these types of projects think.

Comment: You are correct in your statements. Try and reshape data upstream and keep the Vega transforms strictly for the visualisation of the data. However, I still make extensive use of transforms for my visualisations even when the data is in the correct shape and you can see examples here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: I often create HTML dashboards with JS data arrays (> 100k rows) and I find using javascript functions more efficient than VL transforms. I combine devextreme components with vega lite charts to make very flexible dashboards with filtering, data grids etc. If it's possible to aggregate your data server side you should also do that. Reach out if you need some help.